# Ipa Install on Browser Stack

Tags: iphone, ipa, browserstack

How to install .ipa file on the Iphone or Ipad on Browser Stack cloud ?

Though Local testing option, the safari is not recognizing the file and when i tried through DIAWI URL still safari did not recognize the file..

Can anybody suggest me a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com/index.php) service. Through this you can Upload, Send the link, Open the link in Safari on the iOS device and install it successfully.

Note that the .ipa needs to be sign properly and the registered devices can only able to install it.

Other services:

[Testflight app](https://testflightapp.com/)

[Jeffrey sambells](http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution)

Answer (score 0):

BrowserStack primarily offers a cloud base platform for web browser testing. Their mobile emulators currently do not support native app testing. This should hopefully be in the pipeline.